# JPA Criteria API - Multi valued columns

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

Say I have a `many-to-many` relation:

```
@Entity
public class User {
   
...
   @ManyToMany( mappedBy="users")
   public Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<Group>();

   public String name;
...

}
```

And a Group class:

```
public class Group {

    @JoinTable(name="User_Group")
    public Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public String name;
}
```

Now, I want select a user, with all of its groups.
Ideally - it would be a `Set<UserDto>` where `UserDto` is:

```
public class UserDto {
    
    public String name;
    
    public Set<String> groupNames; // assuming concatenating all names straight from query isn't trivial
}
```

I could not find a way to do it, this is as far as i got:

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = JPA.em().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<UserDto> cq = cb.createQuery(UserDto.class);
        Root<UserDto> root = cq.from(User.class);
        SetJoin<User, Group> users = root.join(User_.groups);
        cq.multiselect(root.get(User_.name),  cb.array(users.get(Group_.id)));
        Collection<UserDto> UsersData = new HashSet<>();
```

and got `multiselect selections cannot contain compound array-valued elements`

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that with JPA.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli and JPQL?

Comment: No sorry. That's also JPA